# MinionPro package semibold / medium fonts

Tags: pdftex, minionpro

How can the medium and semibold weights of Adobe Minion Pro be accessed in pdfLaTeX with the MinionPro package? I am confused by [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf), which indicates initially that the `fullfamily` package option enables Medium and Semibold fonts, but then in section 8 suggests that these are only available through substitutions.

I am aware of the two answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103379/minionpro-semibold-medium), the first of which is not a pdfLaTeX solution, and the second of which gives a 'Missing $ inserted' error for me. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with macros to debug this error, or to work out whether MinionPro is actually providing the appropriate `\DeclareFontShape` as required.

A minimal (non-working) example follows, where the {m} font series is rendered as Minion Regular, and the {sb} font series is rendered as bold, rather than Medium and Semibold as desired.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{minimal}
\usepackage[fullfamily]{MinionPro}
\begin{document}
text
\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont text 
\fontseries{sb}\fontshape{n}\selectfont text 
\fontseries{bx}\fontshape{n}\selectfont text
\fontseries{eb}\fontshape{n}\selectfont text
\end{document}
```

If the answer is that the MinionPro package does not fully support these weights, is there something I can put in the preamble to enable their use?

Comment: Do you have those weights? Note that the package supports a number of different possibilities depending on whether you have only the fonts which come bundled with Reader or have purchased commercial fonts from Adobe. If you have only the former, you only have regular and bold weights. At least, I only have those weights from `acroread` 9.

Comment: Yes I do have those weights -- I have the commercial set from Adobe. I've also installed the metrics for them that come with the MinionPro package.

Comment: You need to figure out which version of the fonts you have. For older versions, the CTAN package will work. Newer versions are supported by FontPro. See the comments at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149590/how-to-install-minionpro-tex-package?rq=1 for some useful links. Start by using the CTAN instructions to get the version you have. Use that to determine if the CTAN package is the one you need. If your fonts are newer, you'll want FontPro instead.

Comment: With `fullfamily` (and `medfamily`), you get the semibold weight as standard bold in LaTeX. With `\fontseries{eb}` you can access the normal bold. The medium weight is used for smaller font sizes, which is done automatically. Currently, there is no way to directly access the medium weight.

Comment: @cfr That question has sadly been deleted by the author.

Comment: @MJeffryes Well, there are probably better questions to link to, to be honest. The question was never really clarified sufficiently for anybody to answer.

Comment: @cfr I'm actually trying to solve this problem myself at the moment. The comment by @sebschub above is the closest I've come to an answer (ie, semibold is used for bold, bold is accessible as `eb` and medium is not usable).

Comment: @MJeffryes I suggest asking a new question making clear which version of the fonts you are using and what exactly you've installed. If you are having trouble installing, you need to also say your OS and, for Windows, which TeX distribution you are using.

Comment: @cfr I'm relatively happy with the information I have already, but I might ask a new question at some point at least to put this information in an answer instead of a comment.